# Does meta object in protypal inheritance make sense ES5 above?

Tags: javascript

I see two type of prototypal inheritance function creation pattern here.

```
Function.prototype.inherit = function( base ) {
    function Meta() {};
    Meta.prototype = base;
    this.prototype = new Meta();
}
```

and

```
Function.prototype.inherit = function( base ) {
    this.prototype = new base();
}
```

Former implementation is does not seems to do anything extra! having a Meta function in between, What is its use case?

Comment: One observation the format approach does not works anymore in node 6.10.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the `Meta` function there is to avoid side-effects that might occur by calling the constructor:

```
function Base() {
    console.log("This should not be called when inheriting!");
}

// If you use `new Base()` as a prototype, an unwanted message is logged
```

In ES5, this is built in as [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
this.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype);
```

and in ES6, you can just use [a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```
class Derived extends Base {
    // ...
}
```